# Play a sound when I run my app

Tags: c#, audio

I have created an app, this app helps us to lock the windows phone screen with one touch. Now I want to play a sound when it locks the screen. I've tried to use MediaElement but it doesn't work.

**This is my code (audio is MediaElement's name) :**

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        audio.play();
        new WPRequestScreenClosed().RequestLockScreen();
        Application.Current.Terminate();

    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You are terminating the application immediately after playing the sound.  It probably never has a chance to play.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [MediaEnded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.mediaended.aspx) event to know when the sound is done playing and then close the application at that point.

```
private void MediaElement_MediaEnded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Terminate();
}
```